# How to install vagrant-libvirt plugin on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ruby, vagrant, ubuntu-14.04, libvirt

When I run

```
$ vagrant plugin install vagrant-libvirt
```

on Ubuntu 14.04 I get following error message:

```
Installing the 'vagrant-libvirt' plugin. This can take a few minutes...
Bundler, the underlying system Vagrant uses to install plugins,
reported an error. The error is shown below. These errors are usually
caused by misconfigured plugin installations or transient network
issues. The error from Bundler is:

An error occurred while installing rack (2.0.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rack -v '2.0.1'` succeeds before bundling.

Gem::InstallError: rack requires Ruby version >= 2.2.2.
```

The version numbers in this error message are a bit misleading thou, because I've got ruby 2.3.3 installed via [ppa:brightbox/ruby-ng](https://www.brightbox.com/blog/2016/01/06/ruby-2-3-ubuntu-packages/)

```
$ ruby --version
ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
```

Running the gem command from the error message fails because of insufficient privileges:

```
gem install rack -v '2.0.1' 
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /var/lib/gems/2.3.0 directory.
```

As superuser it works fine:

```
$ sudo gem install rack -v '2.0.1'
Successfully installed rack-2.0.1
Parsing documentation for rack-2.0.1
Done installing documentation for rack after 1 seconds
1 gem installed
```

Thou running `sudo vagrant plugin install vagrant-libvirt` still fails with the same error message.

What's going on here? How can in get this to work?

Comment: can you run 'sudo gem list --local' and 'gem list --local' ? probably giving you different results - generally better to run install without `sudo`

Comment: `sudo gem list --local` and `gem list --local` yield the same results. I'm certainly NOT in favor of granting superuser rights to gem. I've added the results of running `gem install` without `sudo` to my question.